# Create JavaScript object from value with multiple operations using Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

How would I best create this function in [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/)?

```
function get_parts (buffer) {
  return {
    a: buffer.readInt16LE(0),
    b: buffer.slice(2, 4)
  }
}

get_parts(new Buffer('abcd'))
```

The aim is to maintain the function call style and specify (and join) the operations in the simplest way possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a real reason to change that function.

It's clean, readable, and well expresses what you're trying to do.  Assuming you still want to pass it `new Buffer('abcd')` or some equivalent, I can't see that there's anything to do.

If you're looking to make a points-free version of it, that certainly can be done, but I would not think it advisable.  That's useful when it makes the code more readable, but it won't do so here.  Here's my first attempt, and it's not pretty:

```
var get_parts = R.converge(R.unapply(R.zipObj(['a', 'b'])), [ 
                           R.invoker(1, 'readInt16LE')(0), 
                           R.invoker(2, 'slice')(2, 4)
]);
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. I was wondering if there was a way of writing it to remove the need for the explicit argument, but I am happy to take your advice on this.

Comment: Well, perhaps someone can come up with one better than mine -- highly likely -- that is more readable than the original -- unlikely, I think.  To me, points-free is a great technique, but we tend to obsess about it unnecessarily.  The only real clean-up I see to the original function, if your environment permits, would be to use fat-arrows rather than the `function` keyword.